# Coefficient in Taylor's expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

For every positive integer $n$, define the function $f_n(x) = x^ne^{nx^2}$ for $x ∈ \mathbb R$. Find the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the Taylor series (centered at zero) of $f_n(x)$.

I know that the coefficient is $f_n^{(100)}(0)/100!$. But is there a way to obtain this coefficient? I am unable to obtain a general expression of the derivative.

Thank you!

Comment: How about putting $w=nx^2$ in $$
e^w  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{w^k }}{{k!}}} 
$$ and multiplying the whole thing by $x^n$? Note that the result will start $x^n+\ldots$, so the answer is simple when $n>100$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write down the Taylor expansion. We know that $e^x$ is given by $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Thus, we have that $$e^{nx^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(nx^2)^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}n^k}{k!}$$
Thus, we have that
$$x^ne^{nx^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+2k}n^k}{k!}$$
Now we just have to pull out the coefficient of $x^{100}$, we observe that for $n>100$ or $n$ odd we have that this will be $0$. Now if $n\leq 100$ is even, then we will have that the coefficient of $x^{100}$ corresponds with the exponent where $n+2k=100$ or $k=\frac{100-n}{2}$ and this will be an integer that we just plug into for $k$, and get that the coefficient will be
$\frac{n^{ \frac{100-n}{2}}}{(\frac{100-n}{2})!}$. To summarize we will have that it will be
$$\begin{cases}
0 & n\equiv 1\pmod{2}\\
0 & n>100\\
\frac{n^{ \frac{100-n}{2}}}{(\frac{100-n}{2})!} & n\leq 100, n\equiv 0\pmod{2}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I’m sorry but why is it 0 when n>100, or n odd?

Comment: We note that the Taylor expansion looks like $x^n+$stuff, so if $n>100$, then we have the coefficient of $x^{100}$ will be $0$. The $n$ odd case comes from the fact that the exponents in the Taylor expansion look like $n+2k$, and if $n$ is odd, then $n+2k\neq 100$ (where $k$ is an integer), so the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in this case must also be $0$.

Comment: I see. Thanks! (It says that I can’t upvote yet cause I’m new.)